# How to count results from For Loop

Tags: php, loops

How do we count results from For Loop

```
$starting_year=2001;
$ending_year=2015;

for ($x = $starting_year; $x <= $ending_year;$x++) {
    echo "$x <br />";
}
```

how do I count the generation? For example above should be 5

Comment: Why do you need for loop? `$ending_year - $starting_year`isn't enough?

Comment: `$count = $ending_year - $starting_year` So `$count = 2015 - 2001` Ans is `$count  = 14`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this to get the generation count with **for**
loop but I also have a question like why you need **for** loop here just subtract from last year to first year value to get generation

```
$starting_year = 2001;
$ending_year = 2015;
$generation = 0;
for ($x = $starting_year; $x <= $ending_year; $x++) {
   echo "$x <br />";
   $generation++;
} 
echo "No of generation $generation";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help you,

```
<?php
  $starting_year = 2001;
  $ending_year = 2015;
  $count = 0;

  for ($x = $starting_year; $x <= $ending_year; $x++) {
    $count++;
  } 
  echo $count;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for that.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $starting_year=2001;
    $ending_year=2015;
    $generation = $ending_year - $starting_year;
    echo $generation;
?>
```

Comment: I have added same in comment :)